# Appserv command line batch

Tags: mysql, batch-file, installation

I use Java and MySQL with [Appserv](http://www.appservnetwork.com/). I have a database file named "modb.sql" (in a specific directory relative to my program's location), and I frequently need to drop the old database, create a new database (with the same name every time, inside phpMyAdmin) and import the modb.sql file to the new DB.

Is there a way to automate this process and include it with the program or inside a setup file? Instead of doing it manually by me or the user.

I can use another MySQL database manager or C# instead of Java if that would allow the process to be automatic.

Comment: Doing a quick search, I turned up this page http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6151.mysql-batch-imports.aspx which likely has all the commands.  Work on that and post back an attempt to make a batch file.  Post any errors or areas which you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this from the Windows command line or through a Scheduled Task. I don't have Appserv installed, so I can't give you all of the exact file path locations which may vary based on your installation location. You could technically do it from a Java application as well, but that's a lot of overhead and not really automating it like a schedule task will.

You'll basically be calling the `mysql.exe` command directly from your schedule task -- or from a batch file.

First, let's create a new SQL file, perhaps called `DropAndCreateMoDb.sql`. Put your commands to drop (`DROP DATABASE ...`) and recreate the database here. Of course the exact drop command depends on what you call your database and the create command depends heavily on what structure is created by `modb.sql`; you'll also create any permissions that you need to here. This automates the part about dropping and recreating.

Write a batch file. You don't really need to do this, you could call MySQL twice from the schedule task, but we're trying to do this the right way. This is untested, and obviously you'll want to substitute the proper paths and MySQL username/password -- I suggest creating a maintenance account for this so your full credentials aren't in the batch file; the usual disclaimers apply about properly securing your account), but perhaps something like:

`@ECHO OFF
C:\Program Files\Appserv\MySQL.exe -u foo -p bar < C:\data\DropAndCreateMoDb.sql
C:\Program Files\Appserv\MySQL.exe -u foo -p bar < C:\data\modb.sql`

Obviously it doesn't catch any errors and your username and password are in the clear here, but as long as this is on your local development machine for development purposes and you know and understand the risks, it will work.

At this point, you can double-click the `.bat` file and it should drop and recreate your database. To finish it off and fully automate it, you'll add a scheduled task. Go to the Scheduled Tasks control panel and add a new task. Tell it the path to your new `DropAndRecreate.bat` or whatever you decide to call it, tell Windows when you want the task to run, and now it's fully automated.

There are lots of variables here that make the specifics of the implementation very dependent on your exact configuration and so on. Make sure you understand what each step actually does instead of just copying and pasting.